# The image source (either a remote URL or a local file resource)

Tags: typescript, react-native

hello I am new to react native I am facing an issue while I am passing imageURL as a prop I have an onboarding component in which I have an image tag I want to pass the image here as a prop but I am facing an issue I am using typescript in my project here is my onboarding component

```
const OnBoarding: React.FC<{imageUrl: string}> = (imageUrl) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.subContainer}>
        <View style={styles.skipContainer}>
          <Image style={{width:150, height:150}} source={{ uri: imageUrl }} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.nextContainer}>
          <View>
            <Tittle />
            <View style={styles.paragraphSec}>
              <SubTittle />
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                width: '15%',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                marginTop: 12,
              }}>
              <View style={styles.swipe}></View>
              <View style={styles.swipe}></View>
              <View style={styles.swipe}></View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.nextButton}>
            <View style={styles.circle}>
              <Text style={styles.next}>Next</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

and this is my app.tsx file where i import onBoarding component i am new to typescript

```
const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
      // <WelcomeScreen />
      <OnBoarding imageUrl={require("../assets/blur.png")}/>
  );
};
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For this, you need to pass the image source from App itself by specifically checking the condition of having a remote URI or not.

```
const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
const imageSource = isHavingRemoreURI ? {uri: https://remoteURI} : require("../assets/blur.png");
  return (
      // <WelcomeScreen />
      <OnBoarding imageUrl={imageSource}/>
  );
};
```

Usage like:

```
...
<View style={styles.skipContainer}>
   <Image style={{width:150, height:150}} source={imageUrl} />
</View>
...
```

Comment: what isHavingRemoreURI  from where this is come from

Comment: This is not coming from anywhere. it is just as an example for you how you are get know that you have remote URI or local URI.

Comment: Can you describe when you want to use remote URI and when you want to use local URL?

Comment: i dont want to use any  but i got underline error on source when i hover it ,The image source (either a remote URL or a local file resource).

Comment: i am updating my question with an image please check it

Comment: Yes for that as well because with the local path you cannot be able to use URI which you are using in the child component like this `source={{ uri: imageUrl }}`.

Comment: For local path don't need to use uri you can directly user `source={imageUrl}`.

Comment: And the current source which you used is for remote URL. And that warning says this not compatible for both remote and local.

Comment: i update my code like this  <Image style={{width:150, height:150}} source={imageUrl} />

Comment: still get red underline under source with same error

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping it with `JSON.parse` like so:

```
<Image source={JSON.parse(imageUrl)} style={{width: 39, height: 39}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For remote source:

```
source={{uri: 'your_image_path'}}
```